# Run a manual job from a multi-project pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I have a pipeline that contains only **manual** jobs. Is it possible from within a multi-project pipeline to trigger this pipeline and tell it to run only some specific jobs? Like it would mimic a manual trigger.

Example:

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` (in myProject/Foo) file would look like this:

```
...

deploy_to_Production:
 <<: *job_deploy_definition
 stage: deploy
 when: manual
 variables:
    ENV: "Prod"
 only:
   refs:
     - tags

deploy_to_Integration:
 <<: *job_deploy_definition
 stage: deploy
 when: manual
 variables:
    ENV: "Int"
```

From the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file on my multi-project pipeline, I would like to trigger only one specific job:

```
...
production_deploy:
    stage: deploy
    trigger:
        project: myProject/Foo:deployToProduction # Is something like this possible ???
        #strategy: depend
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's only `deploy_to_Production` that you want to trigger from that pipeline, you can split the job up slightly and use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

The trigger pipeline:

```
production_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    DEPLOY_TO_PROD: true
  trigger:
    project: myProject/Foo
    #strategy: depend
```

another trigger pipeline:

```
integration_deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    DEPLOY_TO_INTEGRATION: true
  trigger:
    project: myProject/Foo
    #strategy: depend
```

myProject/Foo:

```
.deploy_to_Production:template:
 <<: *job_deploy_definition
 stage: deploy
 variables:
    ENV: "Prod"

deploy_to_Production:manual:
 extends: .deploy_to_Production:template
 rules:
   - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
     when: manual

deploy_to_Production:triggered:
 extends: .deploy_to_Production:template
 rules:
   - if: '$DEPLOY_TO_PROD == "true" && $CI_JOB_TRIGGERED == "true"'

.deploy_to_Integration:template:
 <<: *job_deploy_definition
 stage: deploy
 variables:
    ENV: "Int"

deploy_to_Integration:manual:
 extends: .deploy_to_Integration:template
 when: manual

deploy_to_Integration:triggered:
 extends: .deploy_to_Integration:template
 rules:
   - if: '$DEPLOY_TO_INTEGRATION == "true" && $CI_JOB_TRIGGERED == "true"'
```

Comment: Thanks but this actually doesn't fit my use case since its not only `deploy_to_Production` that I need to trigger, this was only for the example.

Comment: Maybe you should be using [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules). I've updated my answer again to give a slightly different example which might work for you. However you might want to update your question with your full use case.

Comment: This worked fine for the most part but you will run into this error if you if have both keywords 'when' and 'rules' in the same job : `jobs:deploy_to_Production:manual config key may not be used with 'rules': when`. Any idea of a workaround?

Comment: Ah, updated answer - think you need to move the `when: manual` into the `rules: if:` statement. See [rules clauses](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules-clauses) for more info